# Framer Motion Animate Presence vertically inline

Tags: reactjs, css-animations, framer-motion

I am trying to display a count where when a digit changes the original digit exits downwards and the new digit comes in from the top. When I try to do this, the numbers appear side by side briefly. I have tried using position absolute but then the digits don't exit downwards.

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-mopsa-px3hdi?file=/src/index.tsx) showing the issue I am having.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your motion.divs in a container so the width doesn't change on the animation. Then give the container position relative and a fixed width and every motion.div a position absolute and for each motion.div higher left px.

```
<div className="myComponent">
  <div className="counts-container">
    <AnimatePresence>
      {counts.map((count, index) => (
        <motion.div
          key={index + Math.random()}
          className={`count count-${index}`}
          animate={{ y: 0 }}
          initial={{ y: -50 }}
          exit={{ y: 50 }}
          transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
        >
          {count}
        </motion.div>
      ))}
    </AnimatePresence>
  </div>
  <button onClick={() => setCounts((c) => [...c].reverse())}>
    Change Counts
  </button>
</div>
```

your css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#root {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  place-content: center;
  place-items: center;
  background: rgba(0, 85, 255, 1);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.myComponent {
  display: flex;
}
.counts-container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.count {
  position: absolute;
}
.count-0 {
  left: 0px;
}
.count-1 {
  left: 15px;
}
.count-2 {
  left: 30px;
}
```

MIGHT NOT BE THE BEST SOLUTION BUT IT IS A SOLUTION! :D

Comment: do you know if there is a way to do it without having to dynamically set the width/left? the number can look kinda wonky when its monospaced like this.